# Import Excel file into Access table Run-time Error '-2147352565 (8002000b)'

Tags: ms-access, vba, import-from-excel

Scenario: A user has asked me to provide them a button where they can select a .xls and it will import the data into the corresponding columns in a table.

Question: I will provide the code below, but basically once it tries to open the workbook it gives me the error below. I have googled for a number of solutions but I'm still getting this error.
[image]

```
    Private Sub Command20_Click()
     Dim fdg As FileDialog, vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Dim strSelectedFile As String

Set fdg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fdg
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .ButtonName = "Select"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .Title = "Select Input Files"

        'add filter for excel
        With .Filters
            .Clear
            .Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xls"
        End With
        .FilterIndex = 1
    If .Show = -1 Then
      For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems    'onby be 1
      Dim app As New Excel.Application

      app.Workbooks.Open (vrtSelectedItem)
      app.Worksheets(1).Activate
      For Each rwRow In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows
        ' Do things with the rwRow object
        Next rwRow
        strSelectedFile = vrtSelectedItem
      Next vrtSelectedItem
      Me![txtSelectedFile] = strSelectedFile
    Else     'The user pressed Cancel.
    End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: @Fink, app.Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.. works form me.

I commented out the four lines after `app.Worksheets(1).Activate` and the `Me![txtSelectedFile] = ...`

The `set fd = Nothing` I had to change to `fdg`

I wonder if something is wrong with the Excel file it self. have you tried one created from scratch?

Comment: It turns out it was the excel file. Enabling the macro would cause this error. Made it so that it opens without them and everything works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why `app.Workbooks.Open` causes that error.  However, I will suggest some changes which may or may not help you identify the problem.

1. add `Option Explicit` to your module's Declarations section; then run Debug->Compile from the VBE main menu to show you which variables you haven't Dim'd
2. include `app.Visible = True` after `Dim app As New Excel.Application` so you can monitor what's happening with Excel
3. add `app.Quit` and `Set app = Nothing` before the end of your procedure